# Can not find python3.10 after apt-get installation

Tags: apt, bash, python

I have installed `python3.10` - and verified by attempting to re-install it.  There are some `lib*3.10` files - but no executables:

```
apt-get install -f -y python3.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqgispython3.10.4' for regex 'python3.10'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.10-stdlib' for regex 'python3.10'
libqgispython3.10.4 is already the newest version (3.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

```
/# whereis python3.10
+ whereis python3.10
python3: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/share/python3
root@136e5fcfd4ec:/# ll /usr/lib/python
python2.7/ python3/   python3.8/
```

What might be going on here?

**Update**
This is for `ubuntu-20.04` . Per @steeldriver that is likely the issue: 3.10 came out after that version was released. I should probably use

```
$APT software-properties-common
apt add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt update
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? The messages *Note, selecting ... for regex 'python3.10'* suggest that the python3.10 package is not available in your currently configured repositories and is not in fact installed

Comment: @steeldriver You're right on- would you like to make an answer ? btw I did update the question with `20.04`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an answer on behalf of @steeldriver: if they want to add an answer I will accept theirs.

This is for ubuntu-20.04 . Per @steeldriver that is likely the issue: 3.10 came out after that version was released. I should probably use a special repo that contains all versions of python:

```
$APT software-properties-common
apt add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt update
```